# Stability of Forward Euler in nonlinear ODE

Tags: numerical-methods, stability-theory, eulers-method

I have the following ode: $y^{'}= \frac{k}{\sqrt{y}}$ where k is a positive value.

Applying the Forward Euler method gives the following:  $v^{n}=\frac{\Delta t \ k}{\sqrt{v^{n-1}}}+v^{n-1}$

I'm struggling to show stability on this method. The definition of stability that I'm using is: The method is stable if there exists some real number $C$ such that $|V^{n}|\leq C|V^0|$

The $\frac{1}{\sqrt{v^{n-1}}}$ factor is the one giving me problems, since it makes the equation nonlinear and I can't factorize $v^{n-1}$

I'm aware of the use of fixed point and Newton methods for nonlinear equations, but I don't know if those can fix my problem.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Why should the numerical solution be stable if the exact solution is not bounded in this way?